# Is frozenset a data type or a function in python 3

Tags: python, types, set

Is `frozenset` a data type or a function in Python 3?

Python.org and W3schools state it as a data type of a Set Type, other resources either call it a function or a method. What distinguishes a data type from a function? Before, `range` was a function but now it's a data type. And for example, `string` is either a `text-type`, `text-sequence-type` or a `sequence-type` in various sources.

Is there a method that returns the `data-type` in Python 3? Something like `print(dtype(5.5))` would return `numeric`.

Comment: Yes. use the `type` type, which will return the type of an object. You'll see, `type(frozenset)` is `type`. Note, `numeric` isn't a type. Python has various number types, like `int`, and `float` and `complex`

Comment: I know of a method `type`, for example, if I would use `type(5)`, `type(5j)` I get `Int` and `Complex` whereas I want to get `Numeric` for when I would use `dtype(5)`, `dtype(5j)`.

Comment: `Numeric` isn't a type. Why do you want that?

Comment: Also note, `str` **is the type**. "text-type" is not a type.

Comment: So there is no way of getting categories of data types in Python3? I do understand that `Numeric` or  `Text` is not a type but a category. Like `List, Tuple and Range` would fall into `Sequence` cateogry.

Comment: No, but you can use the abstract-base classes to see if any of these types provide a particular interface, like the sequence interface: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#module-collections.abc But what is it exactly that you are trying to accomplish? Note, W3schools isn't the greatest resource. I would stick to the Python documentation. And the information readily gleaned with python's introspection capabilities.

Comment: Note also, if something were a function, `type` would tell you that too, because `function` is a type (although, it isn't in the built-in namespace). So consider `type(lambda : None)`